# A way to disable sharing Gradle dependencies between dynamically loaded JAR

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies

I have written Java "wrapper" application that downloads the actual application JAR from the web. Basically it's an automatic updater. The application JAR then gets run by the wrapper JAR by loading it in and executing its entrypoint function like so:

```
Class<?> classObject = this.getClassObject();

Method method = classObject.getMethod("run", String[].class);

method.invoke( classObject.newInstance(), (Object)this.getArgs().toArray( new String[0] ));
```

It seems like the application JAR and wrapper JAR both share the same dependencies if the application JAR is loaded in like this. Is there a way to make them not share dependencies between them?

I intend there to be automatic updating. The wrapper JAR might have different versions of dependencies compared to the application JAR installed. That means that if there's an update to one of the dependencies I have to update the wrapper AND application jar, which defeats the purpose of having an automatic updating system.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding the shadow jar plugin and relocating those conflicting dependencies to another namespace.